# I Can't Run Some Ant Tasks In FDT

Tags: ant, fdt, launching

Some of my Ant tasks fail in FDT. The error is usually:

```
BUILD FAILED
Problem: failed to create task or type fdt.invoke.launchConfiguration
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that the Ant script is being run the the same JRE as your workspace.

[image]
[image]